# Date formatting in Lua

Tags: date, lua

I am retrieving a date from a database in the following format:

```
vardate =  '01/20/2017 09:20:35' - mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss
```

I want to convert it to the format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Can I get some guidance on how I could get the format I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Date formatting in Lua is pretty simplistic.](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html) If you only need to convert it from one format to another, and that format does not change, you could simply use `string.match`:

```
function convertDate(vardate)
    local d,m,y,h,i,s = string.match(vardate, '(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+) (%d+):(%d+):(%d+)')
    return string.format('%s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s', y,m,d,h,i,s)
end

-- Call it this way
convertDate('01/20/2017 09:20:35')
```

If you need something more involved, I suggest using an external library.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

```
function ConvertDate(date)
  return (date:gsub('(%d+)/(%d+)/(%d+) (%d+:%d+:%d+)','%2-%1-%3 %4'))
end

-- test
print(ConvertDate('01/20/2017 09:20:35'))
```

Comment: Tony, this worked for me as well, but I went with @SolarBear's suggestion (since it displayed first). But thank you so much, I really appreciate it